# Error importing data into R and spatstat

Tags: r, spatstat

I'm trying to import a text file into R, specifically the spatstat package.  I've loaded a shp file as the window and that worked just fine (displays with *plot()* ).  I can't get the *ppp()* command to run though.  I keep getting this error after running `pp <- ppp(X, Y, window=W)`

```
Error in ppp(X, Y, window = W) : 
  1 out of 904 coordinate values are NA or NaN
```

I've double-checked the file and neither of the X or Y coords have any blank numbers or even negative numbers.

What should I check to deal with this error?  Also, this data is public so I can give it to anybody if they need to have a look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to check the dataset loaded from the file rather than the file itself.  There can be a lot of tricky things in the txt that are hard to catch by eye, a space delimiter instead of a tab, an extra '\n' at the end,  etc.

Try a

```
which(is.nan(X))
```

It looks like there's just one observation giving you a problem.

Comment: I think you mean `is.nan`. And based on the error message, they should probably check `is.na` as well.

Comment: This will not work if X as infinite value. `any(is.infinite(X)) > 0`

Comment: `is.na` worked.  There was an error on the 904th line which is why it gave it as 1 out of 904 when there was over 2000 points.  That should have tipped me off frankly.  Interestingly enough, it was an apostrophe in a text field that was the problem.  Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

I would something like this :

```
ok <- is.finite(X) & is.finite(Y)
if(!ok){
    X <- X[is.finite(X)]
    Y <- Y[is.finite(Y)]
}
pp <- ppp(X, Y, window=W)
```